# How to call a custom executable or script in termnial directly with name?

Tags: command-line, executable

I created an executable file using `gcc` and put it into the `~/scode` folder. How do I run it? I tried typing just the name of the file but it responded with

```
Command not found.
```

I believe there is a defined path the system uses to find executable but don't know how to find out what paths there are. The executable file has the attributes `rwxrwxr-x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run the executable (or script) from within `~/scode`:

```
$ ./executableFileName
```

Or create a directory named `~/bin` and copy the executable (or script) to the directory:

```
$ mkdir ~/bin
$ cp path_to_your_executable ~/bin
```

Now you can directly call executable (script) with the name:

```
$ executableFileName
```

*(To call the executable (or script) with `sudo` or to make it available to other users as well, copy to `/bin` or `/usr/bin` instead.)*